# Moviepy replays audio at the end for half a second

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I used moviepy to add audio to a given video.
I started by checking the duration of the video. If it's shorter than the audio, I slow the video down using:

`video_clip = video_clip.fx( vfx.speedx, (video_clip.duration/audio_clip.duration))`

Then, I added the audio using:

`video_clip = video_clip.set_audio(audio_clip)`

I saved the result with

`video_clip.write_videofile(save_path, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac", fps=24, audio_bitrate="64K", threads=32, ffmpeg_params=['-safe', '0'])`

Everything seems to be OK, except for the last half second of the resulting video, where the audio is replayed right before the end of the video.
I tried

`new_audio_clip = afx.audio_loop(audio_clip, duration=video_clip.duration)`

And added the new audio instead. But nothing changed.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `video_clip = video_clip.set_audio(audio_clip.set_duration(video_clip.duration))`?

Comment: @Rotem Yes, I have that line to ensure both audio and video have the same duration. The issue is still there though

Comment: Since you didn't post a reproducible code sample, we can't verify the issue, and try to find a solution. Even if you share your input audio and video, and a working code sample, the chances for someone to answer are low because MoviePy is not very popular in SO site.

Answer (score 0):

Only setting `buffersize=400_000` fixed it for me.
Default is `200_000`.

I tried many permutations, i.e. setting nbytes, fps, codec, nothing worked.
My audio was 24_000Hz, 32 bit float, Mono. Coming from Google's TTS